# Append function cannot exit for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, append

I want to append files, but Jupiter notebook simply says the file is running but gives no error code and never gives an output.
When I try and stop the notebook it just crashes. Is this a problem with my notebook or the function?

I have tried my code on very simple code like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in x:
    x.append(i)
print(x)
```

...but an output is never given.

This is my actual code:

```
jpgfiles = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.jpg", recursive=True)]
pngfiles = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.png", recursive=True)]

for j in jpgfiles:
    jpgfiles.append(j)
    #print(jpgfiles)

for p in pngfiles:
    pngfiles.append(p)
    #print(pngfiles)

all_files = jpg.files + png.files
#print(all_files)
```

The reason I wonder if it is a code problem is because I don't know if I have trapped the file in some infinite loop or something?
It should be noted that other sections of really complex code still work! it is just when I come to this function that it never stops running...

Comment: you are actually stuck in an infinite loop - you append the filenames at the end of the list you are iterating over. Why do you actually do it? You already have them in a list.

Comment: Just skip both loops and finish with `all_files = jpgfiles + pngfiles`

Comment: What are those two loops supposed to actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would add

```
print(x)
```

to your for loop, you would see, that you created an infinite loop.
you are increasing the array you are working on while looping through the array itself. that's normally very bad practice. you should clone the array and add the elements from the first array to the second one while looping through the first one.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you. I realise now that I needed to append it to a new array. I made an empty variable called file = [] and then did file.append(p) which worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two lists like this:

```
jpgfiles = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.jpg", recursive=True)]
pngfiles = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.png", recursive=True)]

all_files = [*jpgfiles, *pngfiles]
print(all_files)
```